# hping3 Nevers end, even with packet number option

Tags: linux, bash, security, hping

I would like to send only 10 paquets with `hping`, with the -c option. I type :

```
hping3 --flood -c 10 -I ens37 -p 80 -S ............
```

The result of the command is:

```
hping in flood mode, no replies will be shown
```

But it never stops.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't stop because -c is used to count of packets sent AND **received**.

Anytime you specify --flood you will not get reply packets, therefore it can't count them, so it never stops.  Also if there is a firewall between targets you won't get the reply packets so -c can't count them.

From the [documentation](http://www.hping.org/manpage.html)
"-c --count count
    Stop after sending (and receiving) count response packets. After last packet was send hping2 wait COUNTREACHED_TIMEOUT seconds target host replies"